# Hibernate Search @IndexedEmbedded not indexing

Tags: hibernate, search, indexing, hibernate-search

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@SequenceGenerator(name="subjectSeq", sequenceName="subjectSeq")
public class AppInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="subjectSeq")
    public Integer id;

    public Integer district;

    @Field
    @Boost(2.0f)
    public String appName;

    public String thumbnail;

    public Integer statistics;

    @Field
    public String description;

    public Integer publisher;

    public Date publishAt = new Date();

    @ManyToOne
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @Boost(1.5f)
    @JoinColumn(name="type")
    public AppType type;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="appInfo_appCatalog",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="info_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="catalog_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @Boost(1.5f)
    public List<AppCatalog> catalogs;
}

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="appTypeSeq", sequenceName="appTypeSeq")
public class AppType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="appTypeSeq")
    public Integer id;

    @Field
    public String name;
}
```

My searching code is:

```
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity( AppInfo.class ).get();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
              .keyword().fuzzy()
              .onFields("appName", "description", "type.name", "catalogs.name")
              .matching(searchString)
              .createQuery();
```

The question is the "searchString" matching fields "appName" and "description" has results, but the one matching "type.name" or "catalogs.name" doesn't have results

Is entity AppType not indexing?

Comment: You need to add @Indexed annotation on AppType as well.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks so far ok and since you are using *@IndexedEmbedded* the *AppType* should be indexed as well. Why do you think it is not? Have you inspected the Lucene index with [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to check the content? This way you can verify that type.name is in the index and if you can also see what tokens are indexed. Often there is a problem with the analyzers as well. Depending on the analyzer you are using the searchable tokens in the index might not be what you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I learn to use Luke to check. I find "Available fields" contains type.id, catalogs.id, but does not contain type.name, catalogs.name.

Comment: Are you sure that the name fields are not _null_. If the index contains _type.id_ and _catalogs.id_ the embedded indexing seems to be triggered. Maybe it helps if  you add the code you are using for indexing. You can also turn on debug or trace logging. You should then see which data gets indexed

Comment: The data were stored in database. I can fetch them as follows:      {"id":150,"district":1,"appName":"appName","thumbnail":"thumbnail","statistics":null,"description":"description","publisher":1,"publishAt":1339472381703,"type":{"id":1,"name":"web"},"catalogs":[{"id":1,"name":"城市规划","parent":-1},{"id":2,"name":"城市建设","parent":-1}],"status":1,"state":1,"isPopular":1}

Comment: How to trace logging? Is there any config item for logging in persistence.xml?

Comment: Hmm, it seems your names contain Chinese (!?) characters. If so I would definitely check what tokens your analyzer actually produce. Which analyzer are you using for the name fields?

Comment: Regarding logging, it depends where and how you use Search. Search uses slf4j as a logging framework. You need to add a slf4j binding for a particular logging framework (log4j, java logging, ...) and the add the right logging configuration file, eg log4j.properties.

Comment: Hi Hardy, I find the reason. The index updates when a JPA insert(or update) occurs automatically。 When I add a new object: curl --data "{\"district\":1, \"appName\":\"appName\" ,\"thumbnail\":\"thumbnail\", \"description\":\"description\" ,\"publisher\":1, \"type\":**{\"id\":1}**, \"catalogs\":[**{\"id\":1}**,{\"id\":2}], \"status\":1, \"state\":1, \"isPopular\":1}" http://localhost:9000/app/save
, I don't allocate value to type.name or catalogs.name. Although JPA    can work well, Search need complete values for each field of inner entity. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Your answer is helpful for me. I am afraid i carelessly pushed a opposite button for your feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Add @Indexed annotation on AppType class.